# How can Ramban give this reason?

Tags: talmud-gemara, parashat-lech-lecha, ramban

The Gemara in Nedarim 32a gives 3 reasons for why the Jews were put into slavery in Egypt because of Abraham (one is because he made his students fight in the war against the kings, the other is that he asked Gd how he will know that his children will inherit the land, and the third possibility is because he allowed the king of Sodom to keep the people he saved, thereby preventing them from being brought under the Shchinah).

The Ramban however, on the pasuk when Abraham goes down to Egypt, gives the fact that Abraham went down to Egypt on his own as the reason for the Jews’ slavery and even goes as far to call Abraham a sinner. How can Ramban give this new reason that’s not found in the gemara?

Comment: Rav Moshe Feinstein in Derash Moshe criticized this Ramban for your reason and said it must have been inserted by someone else. It is however brought in Rabbeinu Bechaye.

Comment: The second reason you have is pshat in Chumash the first reason about making a draft of talmidei chachamim to go to war is found in the gemera nedarim 32a

Comment: Or are you saying the reason from the Ramban is when Avraham went to Egypt because of the shortage of food?

Comment: @N.T. I can't see any motivation for anyone wanting to do that.

Comment: "How can Ramban give this new reason that’s not found in the gemara?" There are hundreds if not thousands of examples of commentaries giving explanations of biblical passages not found in the Talmud.

Comment: @DoubleAA Here it is faulting Avraham, when there does not seem to be a prior basis in Chazal. It's not "illegal", but it does cause skepticism.

Comment: @N.T. The question wasn't should we be skeptical about the authorship of this claim. It's fine to be briefly skeptical and then realize there's no historical evidence for any such conspiracy and move right along. I personally can't imagine a great talmid chacham like Rav Moshe Feinstein who knew all rishonim cold could have actually expressed the doubts you allege; it must have been an errant student of his who inserted it in his printed works.

Comment: @DoubleAA Touché. Channeling R Menashe Klein…

Comment: @JoelK Allegedly. But do we really think R Klein would have said such things about his respected rabbinical colleague's students?? :P

Comment: @DoubleAA Rav Moshe makes similar claims in a few places. Some say it was a more respectful way of arguing outright. See here from Rav Dovid Cohen: http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/51422-shiur-%E2%80%93-730-%E2%80%93-roe-v-wade-%E2%80%93-what-s-the-torah-s-approach-it-might-be-a-lot-different-than-you-think/

Answer (score 3):

The Ramban's viewpoint is supported by a passage from the [Zohar](https://%5BZohar:%5D%5B1%5D), a significant work in Jewish mysticism. In this text, Rabbi Yehuda explains that because Abraham went to Egypt without a clear divine command, his descendants endured four hundred years of slavery. The key phrase is, "and Abram went down to Egypt." Notably, it doesn't say that God told him to 'Go down to Egypt.' This passage from the Zohar provides strong backing for Ramban's perspective, emphasizing that Abraham's independent journey to Egypt, without clear divine guidance, played a crucial role in the subsequent enslavement of the Jewish people. This affirms the validity and relevance of the Ramban's perspective.

However, Likkutei Sichos<sup>1</sup> offers a more nuanced perspective, explaining that, even according to the Ramban, Abraham, one of our forefathers and a Tzadik (righteous person), couldn't have sinned conventionally due to his lack of a Yetzer Harah (evil inclination). Instead, his "sin" is better understood as a "חטא," derived from the term "חסרון," symbolizing a lack of holiness. This interpretation highlights Abraham's inherent holiness, a concept in harmony with references in both Shabbos 63a and Yerushalmi Brachos 9:5.

<sub>1 [[Original](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wEkqagro-adRh98PBmKNi-2ZCVkH6J0W/view). [Hebrew Translation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tkKqdeFG23g5bC08kC67TkkEzD9LBIDu/view).
[Rabbi Jonathan Sack's English Adapdation](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2474711/jewish/Torah-Studies-Lech-Lecha.htm)]</sub>

Comment: The idea that any tzaddik does not have a yetzer hara is absurd. That would mean they effectively had no choice. (Moshe Rabbeinu might be an exception after Matan Torah, see Meshech Chochmah).

Comment: From the viewpoint that Zohar predates Ramban and the related opinion that Ramban actually had the Zohar, it seems curious he wouldn't quote his source.

Comment: @N.T see

https://www.sefaria.org/Tanya,_Part_I;_Likkutei_Amarim_1.13

Comment: @N.T. And Avraham (עשה יצר הרע טוב, Yerushalmi Berachos 9:5 - cited in the answer - and Sotah 5:5). And David (הרגו בלבבו, ibid., based on Tehillim 109:22). And tzaddikim in general (צדיקים נוטל מהם יצר הרע ונותן להם יצר טוב, Avos d'Rabbi Nosson 32:3, based on the same posuk). Those tzaddikim's choice is not between good and evil, but between good and better.

Comment: @Meir Look at the Binyan Yehoshua in the name of Rashi on the Avos D'rabbi Nassan you quoted. It's clear that it is an exaggeration, and it really means they could overpower their yetzer hara.

Comment: @N.T. All the Binyan Yehoshua is doing is quoting a Rashi on a parallel statement in the Gemara and explaining it. Is R. Nosson not allowed to argue with that Gemara?

Comment: @Meir Obviously not.

Comment: @N.T. Do we need some remedial Klalei Hagemara lessons here? R. Nosson, a tanna, is certainly allowed to argue with R. Yosei Haglili, also a tanna (let alone with Rashi's explanation of R. Yosei).

Comment: @Meir Sorry, I thought you meant someone else. But if Rashi explains the Gemara that way, he would also explain the Avos D'Rabbi Nassan that way too. That is the Binyan Yehoshua's point.