# It would almost seem as though Hashem was tricking Ya'akov into going down to Egypt?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, avot-patriarch-fathers, sheker-false

וַיֹּ֕אמֶר אָנֹכִ֥י הָאֵ֖ל אֱלֹהֵ֣י אָבִ֑יךָ אַל־תִּירָא֙ מֵרְדָ֣ה מִצְרַ֔יְמָה כִּֽי־לְג֥וֹי גָּד֖וֹל אֲשִֽׂימְךָ֥ שָֽׁם׃
“I am God, the God of your father’s [house]. Fear not to go down to Egypt, for I will make you there into a great nation.

https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.46.3

However יעקב had every right to be afraid as his descendants would later suffer greatly there.

I looked in a couple commentaries but did not find anything.

Comment: What's the trick? Did we not become a great nation there?

Comment: But why would he tell him not to worry, surely worry is worthy if your descendants will undergo slavery

Comment: Even slavery was not without its benefits.  See here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/137849/why-were-the-bnei-yisrael-exiled-to-egypt/137850#137850

Comment: @zunior absolutely. Isn't that why HKBH is telling him not to be afraid?